# Using WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE with WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT, waveOutOpen returns WAVERR_BADFORMAT

Tags: c++, windows, surround, waveout

I have been using `WAVEFORMATEX` with WaveOut to play audio in Windows, in stereo at rates from 44.1KHz to 192KHz using `WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT`.  The program is written in C++ and compiled in MinGW.  This is all working correctly:

https://github.com/Raptor007/AutoDJ/blob/60f4debca2103e669a5d1b822b04c73cdcdaf05b/AutoDJ.cpp#L2412-L2435

**Now I'm trying to expand to quadraphonic multi-channel output,** which seems to require `WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE`, a superset of `WAVEFORMATEX`.  Here is the relevant code with those changes applied:

```
WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE wfx;
memset( &wfx, 0, sizeof(wfx) );
wfx.Format.nChannels = want.channels;
wfx.dwChannelMask = (want.channels == 4) ? 0x33 : ((want.channels == 1) ? 0x4 : 0x3);
wfx.Format.nSamplesPerSec = want.freq;
wfx.Format.cbSize = sizeof(wfx) - sizeof(wfx.Format);
MMRESULT wave_out_result = ~MMSYSERR_NOERROR;
if( userdata.HighRes )
{
    wfx.Format.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT;
    wfx.SubFormat = {0x00000003,0x0000,0x0010,0x80,0x00,0x00,0xAA,0x00,0x38,0x9B,0x71}; //KSDATAFORMAT_SUBTYPE_IEEE_FLOAT
    wfx.Format.wBitsPerSample = 32;
    wfx.Samples.wValidBitsPerSample = wfx.Format.wBitsPerSample;
    wfx.Format.nBlockAlign = wfx.Format.nChannels * wfx.Format.wBitsPerSample / 8;
    wfx.Format.nAvgBytesPerSec = wfx.Format.nBlockAlign * wfx.Format.nSamplesPerSec;
    wave_out_result = waveOutOpen( &WaveOutHandle, WAVE_MAPPER, &(wfx.Format), (DWORD_PTR) &WaveOutCallback, 0, CALLBACK_FUNCTION );
}
if( wave_out_result != MMSYSERR_NOERROR )
{
    if( userdata.HighRes )
        fprintf( stderr, "waveOutOpen returned %i%s when attempting float output\n", wave_out_result, (wave_out_result == WAVERR_BADFORMAT)?" (WAVERR_BADFORMAT)":"" );
    wfx.Format.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
    wfx.SubFormat = {0x00000001,0x0000,0x0010,0x80,0x00,0x00,0xAA,0x00,0x38,0x9B,0x71}; //KSDATAFORMAT_SUBTYPE_PCM
    wfx.Format.wBitsPerSample = 16;
    wfx.Samples.wValidBitsPerSample = wfx.Format.wBitsPerSample;
    wfx.Format.nBlockAlign = wfx.Format.nChannels * wfx.Format.wBitsPerSample / 8;
    wfx.Format.nAvgBytesPerSec = wfx.Format.nBlockAlign * wfx.Format.nSamplesPerSec;
    wave_out_result = waveOutOpen( &WaveOutHandle, WAVE_MAPPER, &(wfx.Format), (DWORD_PTR) &WaveOutCallback, 0, CALLBACK_FUNCTION );
    if( wave_out_result == MMSYSERR_NOERROR )
        userdata.HighRes = false;
    else
        fprintf( stderr, "waveOutOpen returned %i%s when attempting int16 output\n", wave_out_result, (wave_out_result == WAVERR_BADFORMAT)?" (WAVERR_BADFORMAT)":"" );
}
```

If I set `Format.nChannels = 2; dwChannelMask = 0x3;` for stereo, the first `waveOutOpen` attempt using IEEE-float format fails with return code `WAVERR_BADFORMAT`, but the second try using PCM format succeeds.

If I try `Format.nChannels = 4; dwChannelMask = 0x33;` for quadraphonic, both IEEE-float and PCM `waveOutOpen` attempts fail with `WAVERR_BADFORMAT`.

However if I set `Format.cbSize = 0;` then everything works correctly with 2 channels in either format, which makes sense since that is essentially what I'd been doing with `WAVEFORMATEX` before.  But this does not work with 4 channels.

**What have I gotten wrong here?**  My ultimate goal is quadraphonic or 5.1 surround output in IEEE-float format.  I'm especially baffled why I can't even get stereo IEEE-float output to work using `WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE` but it works perfectly with `WAVEFORMATEX`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If are using a `WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE` structure, you have to indicate that by setting the correct format tag in the "base" `WAVEFORMATEX`.

```
wfx.Format.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE;
```

See the documentation of the Format member of [WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmreg/ns-mmreg-waveformatextensible).

This makes it possible for the called code (that only has a pointer to a `WAVEFORMATEX`) to discern if it is dealing with a `WAVEFORMATEX` or an `WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE` structure.
In the case of `WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE` the actual audio format is then uniquely identified by the `SubFormat` member.

Comment: Thank you!  That was the problem.  I see now that I misinterpreted the documentation section about backward compatibility with `WAVEFORMATEX` which lists the old values of `wFormatTag` next to their corresponding `SubFormat`.  I thought the intent was to use both together, and that it used `cbSize` alone to discern if it was `WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE`.

Comment: Aha, I also discovered why my incorrect stereo implementation with `wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM` was working when `WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT` was not.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmreg/ns-mmreg-waveformatex  "cbSize ... For WAVE_FORMAT_PCM formats, clients should ignore this member (its value is implicitly zero)."